# Pause python scripts in between tasks, wait for user to continue.

Tags: python, remote-access, file-management

I am looking to write a script that will group up some files on a remote server for me that way I can download the ones I need with a single "scp" command.  I am wondering if there is a way I can have my script pause while I scp my files. What I have so far is working. It would just be more convenient to break this down to one script and one command.

**script on remote server:

```
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        for f in files:
              if ('csv') in file.split('.'):
                     cp_str = ''.join(['cp ', file, ' ~/move_files/.'])
                     subprocess.check_output(cp_str, shell=True)
```

**Then in terminal on my local computer I scp all the files in 'move_files' from my remote server

**Then I go back to the remote server via ssh and empty out that directory

To clarify I want to add something to the script that will make it wait after it has copied the files, giving me a signal that it has copied them.  Then I can scp and resume my script which will go back and delete the files it copied earlier .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way is to wait on input from the user:

```
try:
  resume = input("Press Enter to continue.")
except SyntaxError:
  pass
```

The try/except is because if you just hit Enter with the `input` function, it returns a SyntaxError because it expected some input and you gave it none. But we don't need input, just a signal that you're ready to continue.

If you're on an older version of Python, you can use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Comment: ah! great thank you that worked. I tried that but i didn't allow for the exception and kept getting the syntax error.

Comment: You're welcome! I wonder if it might be possible to incorporate all three tasks into the same script?

Answer (score 1):

The following method is based on a slightly modified script on your remote server and a script on your own PC - but you only have to call the local script.

This is the script for your remote server:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os

path = sys.argv[1]

filelist = ""
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for f in files:
        if ('csv') in f.split('.'):
            filelist = filelist + ", " + os.path.join(root, f)

print(filelist)
```

And this is the script you actually would use. This example uses `paramiko` to create a SSH connection and also directly copies the files your remote script finds with the `paramiko sftp` module.

Necessary inputs are:

- Remote server address [`server`]
- Remote username [`user`]
- Remote top level folder to search for your .csv [`remote_root`]

The script:

```python
#!/usr/bin/python
import paramiko
import subprocess
import os
import getpass

server = "your_server"
user = "username"

remote_root = raw_input("Path to remote folder to search: ")

pw = getpass.getpass()

cwd = os.getcwd()
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

print("Connecting to {}".format(server))

ssh.connect(server, username = user, password = pw)
print("Executing remote script")

stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command("path_to_your_remote_script")

print("Copy remote content to current working directory ({})".format(cwd))
files = stdout.readlines()
file_path = [str(x.strip()) for x in files[0].split(",")[1:]]

sftp = ssh.open_sftp()
for f in file_path:
    path, filename = os.path.split(f)
    sftp.get(f, os.path.join(cwd, filename))

sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```